# Read only spinner

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, spinner, tld

I am learning Jsf.Is there any method for making the spinners read only?I should change the value only using spinners and not directly typing the number.Can i implement that by setting attribute in the spinners.tld file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JSF2.0, you could write your [own spinner JSF component](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2008/11/jsf_20_writing_1.html) except that, instead of using:

```
 <h:inputText id="number" value="#{compositeComponent.attrs.value}"/>
```

(which is a [read-write input box](http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/inputText.shtml) ), you could **use a [`outputLabel`](http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/outputLabel.shtml)**:

```
<h:outputLabel for="number" value="#{compositeComponent.attrs.value}"/>
```

, hence achieving *exactly* what you are after.

Note, **an [`outputText`](http://www.horstmann.com/corejsf/jsf-tags.html#Table4_13) could be as effective**.

[JSF2.0 is released](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/01/jsf_20_pr_relea.html) in PR (Public Review) mode.
It is worth looking into because one of the "pain points" for JSF has always been the complexity that you face in creating components. In JSF 2.0, creating a new component that's made up of existing components is a snap.

Answer (score 3):

Disabling the textfield part of a spinner control is a usability disaster. Please don’t do it. Some of us really *want* to enter the number.

Comment: +1 I agree with Bombe. I nearly always use the textbox part as the buttons are usually so small they're difficult to hit, and if I want to enter 20 (or more), I don't want to have to click 19 times!
Sometimes the answer is to rethink the approach..   :o)